Why the locus of the defects are closed lines?
I am studying kinks in QFT and I find quite confusing the definition of defects. In my notes I have written that if I have a QFT and $\phi$ is a fixed configuration of my field, we call $\Gamma$ the region of spacetime where $\phi$ is close to a local minima of the action but deviates strongly from the global one (vacuum).
As an example, consider the theory $\phi^{4}$ in 1+1 dimensions
$$V(\phi)=\frac{g^{2}}{4}[\phi^{2}-v^{2}]^{2}$$
then we know that the solutions to the EoM are the configurations $$\phi^{S}_{\pm}(x)\equiv\pm v\tanh(\frac{gv}{\sqrt{2}}(x-x_{0}))$$ called kink and anti-kink. From this I would say that the region $\Gamma$ corresponds to the region of spacetime where a fixed $\phi$ looks like a kink, so they are the regions where $\phi$ change sign. The fact that the regions where $\phi$ vanish (called "the locus of the defect") are closed lines (as written in my notes) is it due to the fact that the field must be localized and cannot spread at infinity? Because if I think about a kink I would say that the locus is just an open line ($x=x_{0}=const.$)

Which notes? What page? What does "closed" mean here? That there is no boundary?

With closed I mean that the line is a loop. I can't not share my prof's notes since are protected by copyright. Maybe I can add an image to clarify

Exactly, you generally assume boundary conditions, such as $\langle \phi \rangle >0$. This means that the support of the defect $\Gamma$ cannot be extended to infinity because of boundary conditions, and $\Gamma$ being connected and the place in Euclidean spacetime where, in the partition function, the field changes sign, it must necessarily be a closed (compact without boundary) submanifold. In the case of the kink in $d = 2$ such a submanifold is a closed line.
Regarding the last point: locally $\Gamma$ has the appearance of an open line $x_0 = const.$ but globally by what was stated above it must be a closed line.

Ah yes makes sense, you have $\phi\rightarrow\pm v$ as $x\rightarrow\pm\infty$ right?

Exactly. You confine the kink in a compact region, so that it does not escape at $\infty$
